# Building combinatorial data with AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I am new to AutoFixture and looking especially for a way to create combinatorial data.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

var firstnames = new[] { "John", "Jane", ... };
var lastnames = new[] { "Doe", "Smith", ... };

var persons = Fixture.CreateMany<Person>().ToList();
```

Now I would like to create a list of `Person` class with all combinations of first & lastnames. Is there a way to do it with AutoFixture? I couldn't find any example for this case.

Comment: Maybe FsCheck can do this better? https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/

Comment: Do you expect each request for a `Person` to be unique?
What do you expect to happen once you've requested more `Person` instances than available name combinations?

Comment: @AndreiIvascu I'm looking for a tool that generates a combinatorial data set at once, not per request.

Comment: @SerhiiShushliapin I don't think this is the right tool, but I will take a deep look at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AutoFixture does not have any features that would allow to create combinatorial data. However you could theoretically integrate a generator class that creates full names and by extension instances of class `Person`.

It is likely that other tools can generate combinatorial data more efficiently, but for demonstration purposes lets assume that you can generate all full name combinations using the following LINQ query.

```cs
from firstName in firstNames
from lastName in lastNames
select new FullName(firstName, lastName);
```

You could encapsulate this sequence into a `ISpecimenBuilder` that would keep the state of the last generated name pair. For example using a `IEnumerator`.

This would allow you to use this builder while generating `Person` instances to inject the values for `FirstName` and `LastName`.

You can have a look at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/aivascu/89883f34ea1a3bc0109bfa2328b55288) for more details.

In the end you should have tests that can look like this.

```cs
[Fact]
public void GeneratesCombinatorialNames()
{
    var firstNames = new[] {"Jake", "Lana"};
    var lastNames = new[] {"Gates", "Morris"};
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new PersonCustomization(firstNames, lastNames));
    var expected1 = new[]
    {
        new Person("Jake", "Gates"),
        new Person("Jake", "Morris"),
        new Person("Lana", "Gates")
    };
    var expected2 = new[]
    {
        new Person("Lana", "Morris"),
        new Person("Jake", "Gates"),
        new Person("Jake", "Morris")
    };

    var people1 = fixture.CreateMany<Person>();
    var people2 = fixture.CreateMany<Person>();

    Assert.Equal(expected1, people1.ToArray());
    Assert.Equal(expected2, people2.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! But indeed, I'm looking for a tool which can generate a combinatorial data set automatically, so I don't have to write the logic all over again. Do you know any tool that does that?

Comment: @arkord I have not required a tool like this previously, but a quick search on the internet reveals [several](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/combinatorics) .NET libraries that could fit the requirements you have. The most likely I think is the [combinatorics](https://github.com/eoincampbell/combinatorics) library.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, I will take a look!